# "Failed to resolve: support-fragment " when building using LiveData dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-livedata

Trying to use LiveData with Android Studio `3.1.3` with gradle (build `3.1.3` and wrapper `4.4`) but getting `Failed to resolve: support-fragment` for app `build.gradle` dependencies which are:

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    // LiveData dependencies
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

`LiveData` dependencies seem to conflict with `appcompat` support library since build is successful without `LiveData` dependencies.

Is this a version incompatibility between these 2 libraries?

How can this problem be fixed to allow a build when using these 2 libraries?

**Edit**:

Build succeeds after rolling back support libraries (`appcompat`, `recyclerview`, and `design`) from `27.1.1` to `27.0.2`.

Problem seems to be specifically linked to `appcompat` and `design` support libraries (build only succeed when these are both `27.0.2`) since build succeeds with `recyclerview` support library at `27.1.1`.

Unsure why build fails when using `LiveData 1.1.1` dependencies with `appcompat 27.1.1` and `recyclerview 27.1.1` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I don't see anything out of the ordinary with your dependencies. These are the dependencies within my current project:

```
ext.libraries = [
    //region Dependency versions
    lifecycleVersion : "1.1.1",
    googleSupportVersion : '27.1.1'
    //endregion
]

//region Support dependencies
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
//endregion

//region DataBinding/Lifecycle dependencies
implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:$libraries.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$libraries.lifecycleVersion"
api "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$libraries.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:$libraries.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:$libraries.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:$libraries.lifecycleVersion"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$libraries.lifecycleVersion"
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
//endregion
```

Copy this dependencies and remove the ones that you don't need. It should work okay.

My `ext.android_plugin_version = '3.1.3'` is the same one as my gradle plugin's version, you should look at what version are you using in your build.gradle and update it accordingly. You should look for this `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"`. And remember to replace the `kapt` by `annotationProcessor`.

Lemme know if this fixed the issue.

Comment: Tried using your dependencies (also added room due to project requirements), changed kapt to annotationProcessor, and kept android_plugin_version as 3.1.3 since the project's build.gradle classpath uses 3.1.3. Unfortunately got the same error ("Failed to resolve: support-fragment")

Comment: Build succeeds after rolling back support libraries (appcompat, recyclerview, and design) from 27.1.1 to 27.0.2, unsure why